# bazel failing to install tensorflow with this error java installation could't find/access rt.jar in /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, ubuntu-16.04, bazel

While trying to install tensorflow with gpu on my ubuntu 16.04 box with python 3.5 and cuda 7.5 and cudann 5.1, on configuring I am getting below error. Can some one suggest how to fix this?
[Error seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO8LZ.png)

By the way tried with  lower version of bazel aswell 0.3.2 but still no help. Seems this has been reported by more people... Need google to resolve this issue with Bazel or tensorflow.

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1456 ?

Comment: Had Tried that earlier Gunan but that did not work for me.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Bazel. If the instructions in the Bazel issue above did not work for you, please file a Github issue in the Tensorflow project.

Comment: sure peter will try to file one on github issue for tensorflow. btw i had tried with head on master of tensorflow and 4 versions of bazel ranging from 0.4.2  to 0.3.1..

Comment: while above has still not worked, but **pip3 install tensorflow-gpu** has resolved my case with ubuntu 16.04 , python 3.5 and cuda 7.5 and cudann 5.1